# How to disable text escape on xsl:copy-of

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I build a mechanism that takes all the `<script />` tags and put them at the end of the page.

It works good except that Ampersant `&` characters are encode to `&amp;` even those in JavaScript code which is not what I want.

How can I solve this?

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root></root>
```

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" />
    
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:variable name="body">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="body"></xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:variable>
        
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$body" mode="no-script" />
        
        <xsl:copy-of select="$body//script" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" />
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="script" mode="no-script">
        
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="*[not(self::script)] | @* |comment()" mode="no-script">
        <xsl:if test="name() != 'script'">
            <xsl:copy xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::script)] | @*" mode="no-script" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="body">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Ampersand <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&]]></xsl:text>
            var a = 'a';
        </script>
        <div>Hello World</div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It outputs:

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Hello World</div>
<script xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" type="text/javascript">
            // Ampersand &amp;
            var a = 'a';
        </script>
```

I tried and it works but I wunder if there is a way to keep the `<script>` tags inside the variable `$body`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <xsl:value-of select="$body//script" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" disable-output-escaping='yes'/>
</script>
```

Comment: Having XSLT construct text/html output with embedded script can be tricky. Currently you have not clearly stated what your target result should be, HTML 4, HTML5, XHTML 5? Which XSLT processor do you use?

Comment: I'm using HTML5 and saxon9-9.0.0.8

Answer (score 0):

The HTML output method in XSLT 2.0+ should not perform escaping for the text within a `script` element.

However, there's a difference between 2.0 and 3.0. In 2.0, this only applies to a `script` element in no namespace. In 3.0, provided you're outputting HTML5, it also applies to a `script` element in the XHTML namespace.

Comment: Ok but why it does not work then? I have XSLT2 and the script does not have any namespace

Comment: Your script element (indeed all your output) is in the XHTML namespace, and it turns out Saxon is still using the XSLT 2.0 rules where escaping is disabled in script elements only if they are in no namespace - even if you select HTML5, which you didn't (HTML5 becomes the default in Saxon 10, but in 9.9 it was still HTML4). I'll raise an issue and create a test case.